# How do Japanese viewers watch the Japanese dub of RWBY?

Tags: rwby

Out of curiosity, I'd like to know if RWBY is actually aired on television, or it's available on the Japanese version of Crunchyroll, or how else it is viewed.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RWBY):

> A local Japanese dub is being developed by Warner Bros. Home Entertainment Japan, with plans for release on Blu-ray and DVD in 2015, marking the first time an American-produced anime-inspired series has been marketed in Japan.

So it appears that the Japanese release is limited to those media.